# Python: determining the array of centroids with highest likelihood for k-means clustering (scipy)

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, k-means

I'm using the scipy implementation of k-means and need a way to loop the calculation n times, record the output array of centroids for each loop, and calculate the output with highest likelihood.  *edit* I'm setting k = 4, so each solution has 4 elements.  I need to determine centroid array (ie set of 4 elements) that occurs most frequently.

My centroid arrays look something like:

```
[[ 75]
 [115]
 [163]
 [ 16]]
```

In running the code manually, there are 4-6 solutions that turn up due to the random properties of k-means.  Essentially I'd like to count the occurrences of each array over n and return the most likely array.

*EDIT* to clarify, based on Jblasco's interpretation of question.

Each time the algorithm runs it returns a centroid array like the one above.  Running the algorithm 3 times I'd have something like:

```
[[ 75]  [[ 73]  [[ 75]
 [115]   [112]   [115]
 [163]   [167]   [163]
 [ 16]], [ 14]], [ 16]]
```

I'd like to accomplish two main things:

1) Loop the code that produces these centroids
2) Determine the most likely (frequent, common) solution, which in this case would be:

```
[[ 75]
 [115]
 [163]
 [ 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you will get n times an array that looks like that one you show, and you want to count the number of times 75 is in the array, 115 is in the array and so on and so forth. If that is correct, I'd think of something like:

```
keep_count = {}
for attempt in range(n):
    get_one_of_those_arrays  <-- sorry, no idea how the function of k-means work
    for result in array:        
        if keep_count.has_key(result):
            keep_count[result] +=1
        else:
            keep_count[result] = 1
```

And now keep_count has all the ocurrences of each resulting number. A slightly more elegant way uses defaultdict:

```
    import collections
    keep_count = collections.defaultdict(int)  # initializes dict to int 0, no more if
    for attempt in range(n):
        get_one_of_those_arrays
        for result in array:
            keep_count[result] += 1
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  I'm actually looking for the set of 4 values that is most common.  I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I understood what you meant, let's start again, ok? Similar way of thinking for a similar problem. I admit it is not the most elegant possibility, but I think it works and it is intuitive:

```
keep_count = {}
for attempt in range(n):
    array = get_one_of_those_arrays  <-- sorry, no idea how the function of k-means work
    array = tuple(array.reshape(4))
    if keep_count.has_key(array):
        keep_count[array] +=1
    else:
        keep_count[result] = 1
```

Now we just need to find the position of the maximum:

```
max_value = max(keep_count.values())
max_pos = keep_count.values().index(max_value)
most_frequent = keep_count.keys()[max_pos]
```